# This field is required error but field is in the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I have a form which I initiallize with request.POST, but, even if thje form has the correct field it isnt valid, what am I missing?

```
def some_view(self, request):
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():

(Pdb) form.data
<QueryDict: {u'csv_file': [u'some_csv_file.csv'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'csrftoken']}>
(Pdb) form.is_valid()
False
(Pdb) form.errors
{'csv_file': [u'This field is required.']}
```

Comment: You didn't show the form, but presumably `csv_file` is a FileField. It requires an actual file, in `request.FILES`, not just a filename.

Comment: ah, I thought it would come in request.POST, hmm then you are correct, request.FILES is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a FileField in a Django form, there are 2 things to do:

```
1. In your template, in the form tag, add enctype="multipart/form-data"
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

2. Pass the request.FILES when creating the form
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
```